# JavaFX Tableview limit the number of digits after point

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a table based on tableview , it is populated by double values I recieve trougth API , and I want to display only 3 digits after point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StringConverter` to get the desired format, and install it, using a `TextFieldTableCell` like this:

```
    threeDigitColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<RowModel, Double>forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Double>() {
        private final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

        {
             nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
             nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
        }

        @Override public String toString(final Double value) {
            return nf.format(value);
        }

        @Override public Double fromString(final String s) {
            // Don't need this, unless table is editable, see DoubleStringConverter if needed
            return null; 
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Works. But needs a few adjustments.  TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn has no need for types. And it should be Numberformat df = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();

Comment: @user3224416: Sorry, I might have made a mistake in the copy/paste process... Fixed. You could use @James_D's `String.format()` version as well. And about need for types, it depends on Java version, I think. My IDE complained if omitted. ;-)

Comment: @haraldK Could you please explain how to use this when the table is editable? Maybe I'm searching with the wrong keywords but I can't manage to find information on that DoubleStringconverter. How do I use that in combination with NumberFormat? Is `return Double.valueOf(s);` enough in the fromString function?

Comment: First of all, [DoubleStringConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/converter/DoubleStringConverter.html) is part of the standard JavaFX API. If you want to edit the table, it's probably better to extend that. The OP's question was how to display only 3 digits. To use the above class in an editable table, you could use `Double.valueOf(s)` or `nf.parse(s).doubleValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom cell factory on the table columns:

```
Callback<TableColumn<S, Double>, TableCell<S, Double>> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<S, Double>, TableCell<S, Double>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<S, Double> call(TableColumn<S, Double> col) {
        return new TableCell<S, Double>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Double value, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(value, empty) ;
                if (value==null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(String.format("%.3f", value.doubleValue()));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
tableCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

(where you replace `S` with the data type for the table).

Comment: This is what I used to do. After I found `StringConverter`, I find it cleaner and more reusable. But for the OP's problem, I think it works just as good. :-)

Comment: But you can only use a `StringConverter` if you are using something like a `TextFieldTableCell`, which seems unnecessarily heavy if you are not making the column editable (and in that case, you'd probably want a custom `TextField` anyway, to prevent non-numeric entry).

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily heavier, as no `TextField` is instantiated unless you are actually editing the cell. Also, a `StringConverter` can be reused in `ComboBox`, `ListView` etc. Would have been easier if you could have just provided a `StringConverter` directly to lists and tables, like you can with combobox though...